# How to have to array list depending on each other

Tags: java, android, indexing, spinner

I'm trying to create a login form where you select an item from a spinner and then you need to put in the right code in a text field to be able to proceed. This is what I got.

```
Spinner schoolList = findViewById(R.id.schoolList);

    ArrayAdapter<String> schoolListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(CreateAccount.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, schools);

    schoolList.setAdapter(schoolListAdapter);
private String[] schools = new String[]{
        "School 1",
        "School 2,
        "School 3"
};


private String[] schoolCodeArray = new String[] {
        "password1",
        "password2",
        "password3"
};
```

I know that you could check to see if School 1 = password1 and so on but this list will be very long and I'm therefore looking for a better way. Something like taking the index of the selected school and checking if that index is equal to the index from the schoolCodeArray and matches what is put in the text field. I hope that you understand what I'm looking for. I appreciate all help!

Comment: Create a class which holds a school and code together; then create a single array of that class.

Comment: Why not using Array of Array? String[][] = new String[]{ new String[] {"School1", "Password1"}, new String[] {"School 2", "Password2" } };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have initialized the `EditText` by `findViewById`(), so try this and put your code inside `onItemSelected`:

```
    String[] schools = new String[]{
            "School 1",
            "School 2",
            "School 3"
    };


    final String[] schoolCodeArray = new String[] {
            "password1",
            "password2",
            "password3"
    };

    Spinner schoolList = findViewById(R.id.schoolList);
    ArrayAdapter<String> schoolListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(CreateAccount.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, schools);
    schoolList.setAdapter(schoolListAdapter);

    schoolList.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (schoolCodeArray[position].equals(editText.getText().toString().trim())) {
                // your code here
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you supposed to have two spinner one for school and other one for password, then consider ordering of items may different as well. Make your logic flexible.
To consider above create a `HashMap` where consider school as a key and password as a value.

```
HashMap<String, String> credentialMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
credentialMap.put("School 1","Password 1")
credentialMap.put("School 2","Password 2")
```

Once user selects item from both of the spinner then on some button action you need to validate it. To do that

```
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
         public void onClick(View v){
            if(credentialMap.containsKey(schoolSpinnerItem)){
              if(credentialMap.get(schoolSpinnerItem).equals(passwordSpinnerItem)){
                // Login success
              }
              else{
                 // Login failed
              }
            }
         }
     });
```